# Is there a way to convert a List<T> to a PagedData<T> while the backing paging source data doesn't use room db

Tags: android-paging, pagedlist, android-paging-3

- I do have a paged data source that returns a `PagedData<T>` data that is displayed with the  pagedAdapter after initial load from SQLite. After some server transactions,I receive a list
  of `List<T>` and after transforming and caching it need to display it.
- I know this would be easy with Room db but that's off the table for now.How do I update the initial paged list and create a new pagedList and then push it to the adapter.
- Tried using a map transformation on the new server list to PagingDataObject but it's not possible as far as I know. `list.map { item -> {PagingData<item>}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can implement your own pagingSource, it's not necessary to use Room.
The first half of [paging3 codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#5) shows you exactly how you can achive that. Create your pager like this :

```
Pager(
      config = PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 10,
        enablePlaceholders = false
     ),
      pagingSourceFactory = { MyPaginSource() }
).flow
```

and implement `MyPaginSource` like this :

```
class MyPaginSource() : PagingSource<Int, MyItem>() {

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, MyItem> {
    if(params.key == null){
        //load initial list from where ever you want, and create your own key 
        //to load next page of data
        val firstPage = //todo
        val nextKey  = //todo
        return LoadResult.Page(
                data = firstPage ,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = nextKey
        )
    } else{
        //load the other pages based on your key, for example from server 
        val newPage = //todo
        val nextKey  = //todo if you need to continue loading
        return LoadResult.Page(
                data = newPage ,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = nextKey
        )
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is what I currently have and been using but I run into issues where the load method never gets called even after calling invalidate after getting a new list.

Comment: Other  case I observed is , for each invalidate of the paging source I have to define a new a new pager source as I kept getting an exception cannot pass same paging source.

Comment: I had the same problem as you mentioned in your second comment, the problem was that i declared my PagingSource as an object and i was trying to pass it again to pager instead of creating a new instance of it.